# PHP check date from MySQL an add 1 Year

Tags: php, mysql

My PHP script reads the timestamp stored in my MySQL database and display it in PHP like this: 24 Aug 2014!
That's right so far, but now I want that he hangs one year that it reads as follows: 
24 Aug 2015!

Here is my code:

`$date = $check_if_user['abo_fact'];
$user_fact = date('d M Y', $date);`

Thx for help ;)

Comment: `SELECT abo_fact + INTERVAL 1 YEAR`?

Comment: Do you want to add 1 year to a date (in Php)?

Comment: Its done, it works now. Sorry, i`m new here :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $new_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 year', strtotime($user_fact)) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this code:

```
$date = $check_if_user['abo_fact'];
$user_fact = date('d M Y', strtotime($date . " +  1 year"));
```

Comment: It is advisable that you format your code properly.